# Mechanism of acid-catalyzed ring opening of a cyclopropane ring

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination, ring-strain

I have a question regarding following synthesis which apparently only needs a sour medium to occur:
[image]

What exactly happens as a mechanism? What I thought was: The alcohol group gets protonated and forms a stable carbocation at it's tertiary position. This charge can now wander to the tertiary carbon next to it; but an H-Shift should not be possible. What is the mechanism here?

Comment: Ring opens instead of shift.

Comment: Because of the carbocation in this position? Will it destabilize the ring because it is sp2?

Comment: While acids are indeed sour, the medium is acidic. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the mechanism should be somewhat like this (after the formation of carbocation) -

[image]

It would account for the product shown, but I am not sure if it's correct. I feel it's more favourable for a dehydration to occur with the hydrogen from the ring itself (shown on the dash at the top) to form this -

[image]

This double bond is conjugated and more substituted, so I should have thought that this would be the major product.

Comment: If my mechanism is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Probably elimination is concerted with ring opening, so "less favorable" product is created.

Comment: Did the OP's question state that the observed product was the major product? No.

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks for the insight. Yes, if it's a single step then to form my proposed product it would need to start making a double bond before the ring was completely broken - which of course would be difficult owing to angle strain.

Comment: @user55119 Great point! It shows how reading things closely matters a lot :)